# How to trigger a script on a Teamcity CMD step failure?

Tags: bash, teamcity

I have a TeamCity job that runs a CMD step with an inline bash script.

If a user cancels the job or it fails, I want to send a notification via tcp to another system.

I put a trap handler into the script but the trap is not triggering, suggesting that it's not being passed any of the usual signals.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

function handle_error() {
    echo "TRAPPED $1"
    exit 1;
}

trap 'handle_error ERR' ERR
trap 'handle_error INT' INT
trap 'handle_error TERM' TERM
trap 'handle_error QUIT' QUIT
trap 'handle_error EXIT' EXIT

for i in $(seq 30); do echo $i; sleep 1; done
```

I get the following output when I start the job and then cancel it.

```
[11:34:36][Step 1/1] Starting: /opt/teamcity_agent_a11/temp/agentTmp/custom_script4059331588446614618
[11:34:36][Step 1/1] in directory: /opt/teamcity_agent_a11/work/84217cc201b5cd23
[11:34:36][Step 1/1] 1
[11:34:37][Step 1/1] 2
[11:34:38][Step 1/1] 3
[11:34:39][Step 1/1] 4
[11:34:40][Step 1/1] 5
[11:34:43][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 137
[11:34:43][Step 1/1] Step Command Line interrupted
[11:34:44]Build was interrupted. Artifacts will not be published for this build
[11:34:44]Build canceled
```

The TRAPPED message does not appear. Is there a way to make this work?

Alternatively, is there a way to configure TeamCity to trigger another script if this job fails or is cancelled?

--**UPDATE**--

I've now discovered that since **10.0.2**, TeamCity offers control of this behaviour via parameters.

By setting `teamcity.force.kill.process.on.cancel.build=false`, Teamcity will first send a **SIGTERM** and then follow it with a **SIGKILL** after **60** seconds  (overridable via `teamcity.force.kill.process.on.cancel.build.timeout.sec`) if still alive

More details in this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-13367#comment=27-1573848

Comment: It is working fine. You just need to add some some statements and try it. For e.g. I just did a `sleep 10` at the end and did a Ctrl+C and SIGINT was trapped properly.

Comment: Hi Inian - sorry I should have said I tried that already - Updated my question. I dont see the result of the echo "TRAPPED " when I cancel the job.

Comment: Is there a part of the script you are not showing here? How are the logs generated? How is the script started/stopped

Comment: It's running under Teamcity as per the title. Starting and stopping via the UI. The traps work fine from a normal terminal execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Exit Codes With Special Meanings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) description, exit code `137` means that the process was killed with `SIGKILL`, which

> can not be caught, blocked or ignored

according to the [docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_01.html) (see section `12.1.2. Usage of signals with kill`)

Comment: ahh - that would explain. evil Teamcity!

Answer (score 2):

I've now discovered that since **10.0.2**, Teamcity offers control of this behaviour via parameters.

By setting `teamcity.force.kill.process.on.cancel.build=false`, Teamcity will first send a **SIGTERM** and then follow it with a **SIGKILL** after **60** seconds  (overridable via `teamcity.force.kill.process.on.cancel.build.timeout.sec`) if still alive

More details in this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-13367#comment=27-1573848